# EXC_BAD_ACCESS, KERN_PROTECTION_FAILURE preview on Xcode 11 using SwiftUI

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, exc-bad-access, xcode11

As soon as I try to preview my code, it crashes with these errors. I already posted something else on this matter but seems to be connected. As soon as one file crashed, all the others followed.

Any ideas?

```
Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes:       KERN_PROTECTION_FAILURE at 0x00007ffee4b53ff0
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

External Modification Warnings:
Thread creation by external task.

VM Regions Near 0x7ffee4b53ff0:
    MALLOC_LARGE           00007fb8683d3000-00007fb8683f4000 [  132K] rw-/rwx SM=PRV  
--> STACK GUARD            00007ffee1354000-00007ffee4b54000 [ 56.0M] ---/rwx SM=NUL  stack guard for thread 0
    Stack                  00007ffee4b54000-00007ffee5354000 [ 8192K] rw-/rwx SM=ALI  thread 0

Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libswiftCore.dylib              0x00007fff512e9a86 swift_getGenericMetadata + 102
1   com.apple.AttributeGraph        0x00007fff2fc601cd __swift_instantiateGenericMetadata + 29
2   com.apple.AttributeGraph        0x00007fff2fc61d1d protocol witness for static Formula.add(_:to:) in conformance Formulas.Offset<A, B> + 77
3   com.apple.SwiftUI               0x00007fff2c378b3f closure #1 in static AGGraphRef.<< infix<A>(_:_:) + 15
4   com.apple.SwiftUI               0x00007fff2c378bef thunk for @callee_guaranteed (@unowned UnsafePointer<A>) -> (@unowned Attribute<A.Value>, @error @owned Error) + 15
```

EDIT:

```
import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {



    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        return true
    }

    // MARK: UISceneSession Lifecycle

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, configurationForConnecting connectingSceneSession: UISceneSession, options: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) -> UISceneConfiguration {
        // Called when a new scene session is being created.
        // Use this method to select a configuration to create the new scene with.
        return UISceneConfiguration(name: "Default Configuration", sessionRole: connectingSceneSession.role)
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didDiscardSceneSessions sceneSessions: Set<UISceneSession>) {
        // Called when the user discards a scene session.
        // If any sessions were discarded while the application was not running, this will be called shortly after application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions.
        // Use this method to release any resources that were specific to the discarded scenes, as they will not return.
    }


}
```

```
import SwiftUI

struct PisteRow: View {
    var pista: Structure

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            padding()
            pista.image
                .resizable()
                .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
                .clipShape(Circle())
            Text(pista.name)
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}

struct PisteRow_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        PisteRow(pista: pisteData[0])
            .previewLayout(.fixed(width: 300, height: 70))
    }
}
```

These are the files requested, App Delegate and the SwiftUI File that won't allow preview. Thanks.

Comment: Can you post the contents of your `AppDelegate.swift` And the SwiftUI file that you aren’t able to preview?

Comment: I just did! If you could just take a look @PeteMorris

Comment: @AlbertoGiardino Could you able to find the exact cause of this crash? or a method to debug this issue?